# Quickblox Sing Up returns XML instead of JSON

Tags: json, xml, rest, http, quickblox

Although I'm requesting JSON, sing up process always returns me XML

**Request:**

```
Request
  -method: "POST"
  -resource: "/users.json"
  -host: "https://api.quickblox.com"
  -protocolVersion: 1.1
  -headers: array: 3
    0 => "Accept: application/json"
    1 => "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version: 0.1.0"
    2 => "QB-Token: ..."
  ]
  -content: "user%5Blogin%5D=user_1&user%5Bpassword%5D=password_1&user%5Bexternal_user_id%5D=1"
}
```

**Response:**

```
Response {
  -protocolVersion: null
  -statusCode: null
  -reasonPhrase: null
  -headers: array: 17 [
    0 => "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
    1 => "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"
    2 => "Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"
    3 => "Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8"
    4 => "Date: Wed, 09 Sep 2015 12:02:46 GMT"
    5 => "ETag: "....""
    6 => "QB-Token-ExpirationDate: 2015-09-09 14:02:43 UTC"
    7 => "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version: 0.1.1"
    8 => "Server: nginx/1.6.2"
    9 => "Status: 200 OK"
    10 => "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000;"
    11 => "X-Rack-Cache: miss"
    12 => "X-Request-Id: ..."
    13 => "X-Runtime: 0.015210"
    14 => "X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1"
    15 => "Content-Length: 630"
    16 => "Connection: Close"
  ]
  -content: """
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n
    <user>\n
      <blob-id type="integer" nil="true"/>\n
      <created-at type="datetime">2015-09-09T12:02:45Z</created-at>\n
      <custom-data nil="true"/>\n
      <email nil="true"/>\n
      <external-user-id type="integer">1</external-user-id>\n
      <facebook-id nil="true"/>\n
      <full-name nil="true"/>\n
      <id type="integer">...</id>\n
      <last-request-at type="datetime" nil="true"/>\n
      <login>user_1</login>\n
      <owner-id type="integer">...</owner-id>\n
      <phone nil="true"/>\n
      <twitter-id nil="true"/>\n
      <updated-at type="datetime">2015-09-09T12:02:45Z</updated-at>\n
      <website nil="true"/>\n
      <user-tags nil="true"/>\n
    </user>\n
    """
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which programming language and platform/sdk do you use?

Comment: @IgorKhomenko none, just a rest api.